# How do I rotate my display when not using an X Server?

Tags: command-line, graphics, display, monitor

I have a widescreen monitor that rotates. I'm trying to use it in 'landscape' mode (vertical). This is easy in the GUI.

How do I rotate my display when I am *not* running an X Server or when I am viewing a [Virtual Console / Terminal.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can rotate your virtual framebuffers using fbcon.  0 through 3 to represent the various rotations:

- `0` - Normal rotation
- `1` - Rotate clockwise
- `2` - Rotate upside down
- `3` - Rotate counter-clockwise

These can be set from the command line by putting a value into the correct system file.  Rotate the current framebuffer:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate
```

Rotate all virtual framebuffers:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate_all
```

If you want this to happen automatically when you start your system, you need to modify your boot loader configuration to give it the correct options.  In `/etc/default/grub` add `fbcon=rotate:1` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="fbcon=rotate:1"
```

(Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` after changing this file.)

Sources: [Rotate Screen, not running X windows](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1216868.html), [Rotate console on startup (Debian)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68369/rotate-console-on-startup-debian)

Comment: Relies on `CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE_ROTATION=y`

Comment: Confirmed this work in virtualbox linux client too!!

Comment: Does not work in NVIDIA Jetson Nano supplied Ubuntu. /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate content will not change. rotate_all makes access denied even as root.

Comment: It isn't a real file and it doesn't have contents.  You can't read that "file".   You can only write to it.  Have you tried the command exactly with copy and paste?

Comment: Works for me in Debian 9 on an Intel IGP. What a joy to have a "portrait mode" full HD console :-)

Comment: For those interested, I own a Lenovo Yoga, which when busy in command line mode i use "upside down" from tty, with tmux.
The answer worked wonders.
For those who change modes frequently, one can add an alias in the ./bashrc file:
I added, based on this answer:

alias rotate_default='echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate'

and

alias rotate_upsidedown='echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate'

Comment: Works for using me Ubuntu 20 on RasPi 3.

Comment: What about two monitors setup? My main monitor is in rotation 0, the other one I would like to have in rotation 3, but only one fb0 is in graphics...

Answer (score -10):

You can only rotate your display with some kind of X server. A virtual console as well as framebuffer has no support for rotating.

But maybe you can run some small X window manager like awesome and a terminal in full-screen mode. In this case you would get the rotation feature and it still feels like a console.

Comment: Ha! I used to rotate by frame buffer in Linux back when I had CRTs!