# How do I prevent unattended screen rotation at login?

Tags: unity, login, lightdm, tablet, display-rotation

Recently I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo ThinkPad X230 Tablet. It works just great! I'm experiencing only two minor problems, both are wired with the [convertible screen](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51mlomDVzKL._SY450_.jpg). This one, that annoys me is the subject of this question.

**When I login to Unity the display orientation goes to portrait view mode.** So, I must press the screen rotation button to get back to landscape view mode.

The default view within LightDM is landscape. The problem doesn't exist when I unlock Unity, only when I log into. This problem doesn't exist when I login to Gnome. But primary I'm using Unity, so my question is: **How do I force Unity to stay in landscape view mode immediately after logging into?**

Update 1:

- I found that the problem doesn't exist for *guest-session* and for newly created users.
- It looks like some application rotates the display.
- I already have tried, without success, some solutions based on the answers of these questions:

  - [How do I rotate my display when not using an X Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237963/how-do-i-rotate-my-display-when-not-using-an-x-server)
  - [Screen randomly rotates on Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968169/screen-randomly-rotates-on-ubuntu-17-10)
- **Only `xrandr -o normal` placed as command within Startup Applications is a kind of ugly workaround.**

Update 2:

- The original title: How do I force Unity to stay in landscape view immediately after logging into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to understand where the problem comes from:

- The tablet has a [builtin screen rotation button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kNSv.jpg). I haven't set up anything about this button. It is working by default with Unity/Gnome.
- When I press this button the screen is clockwise rotated and the current screen orientation is stored in the file `~/.config/monitors.xml`. This file doesn't exist unless this button is pressed, thus in the *guest-session* (as it mentioned in the question) the problem doesn't exist.
- I don't have an idea which *"feature"* creates this file when I'm pressing the button.
- When I'm logging-out, *"something"* edits the file `~/.config/monitors.xml` (if it exists) and changing the orientation on random pricipal. Maybe *"it"* attempt to turn the orientation  back to `normal`, but *"it"* doesn't work properly. **And this is the issue.**

---

To fix this for a certain user, just add the following Cron job - `crontab -e`:

```
@reboot sed -i 's#<rotation>.*</rotation>#<rotation>normal</rotation>#' "$HOME/.config/monitors.xml" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

- Replace `normal` with your desired orientation.
- This command will substitute `<rotation>something</rotation>` with `<rotation>desired value</rotation>` within the file `~/.config/monitors.xml`.

Unfortunately this workaround will fix the problem only when you start or reboot the system. When you log-out and log-in the problem may appear again. To fix this you can add your `xrandr` command in the [Startup Applications](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/566421).

[image]