# Keyboard shortcut for rotating Ubuntu 17.10 Screen

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.10, touchscreen, wayland

I somehow rotated the Ubuntu 17.10 screen so it ended up upside down (I think I accidentally triggered a keyboard shortcut).  I could not get it to rotate back by clicking the [screen rotate button in the task menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968169/screen-randomly-rotates-on-ubuntu-17-10), so I had to reboot.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for rotating the screen 180 degrees?  The rotation happened on an HP Envy laptop with a touchscreen.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's any by default, but You can easily set the one You like!
Just tap <kbd>Super</kbd> to open Dash, search for `Keyboard`, go to `hotkeys` tab and create new one.
The commands You need are: `xrandr -o inverted` and `xrandr -o normal`.

Comment: Had to use: `xrandr --query` to obtain the device, then use `xrandr --output <device> --rotate normal` to fix my screen.  This problem is infuriating!

Answer (score 10):

I also have an HP. Open the screen as far as you can then tilt the laptop back and the screen will auto rotate back to the correct orientation. Then hit the super key(windows key)+ o and that will lock your screen auto-orientation.

Comment: This won't work for devices without orientation sensor