# Ubuntu 17.10 screen rotation

Tags: suspend, display-rotation

My screen rotates randomly (sideway, upside down...) if I close the lid (suspend) and put my laptop in my bag.

I know you can lock it but when Ubuntu boots, it doesn't show that option (image). It only shows after waking up but only sometimes.
Is there an easy way to lock the screen rotation permanently?

[image]

Comment: See: [Screen randomly rotates on Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968169/screen-randomly-rotates-on-ubuntu-17-10/968173)