# Screen rotates after closing HP laptop's lid with Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: 18.04, suspend, laptop, display-rotation

I have checked [other posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035209/how-to-turn-off-screen-rotation-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts) about [randomly rotating screens](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047139/ubuntu-keeps-randomly-rotates-screen), and screens that rotate after sleep. I have tried the following to no avail:

1. Lock screen rotation:

   [image]

   Problem persists.
2. Disable GNOME orientation plugin:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.orientation active false
   ```

   Problem persists.
3. Disable/Uninstall `iio-sensor-proxy`:

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop iio-sensor-proxy.service
   sudo systemctl disable iio-sensor-proxy.service
   sudo apt-get remove iio-sensor-proxy
   ```

   Problem persists.

Every time I close the lid, the laptop wakes up sideways and I have to run:

```
xrandr -o normal
```

Is there a bug somewhere? Have I missed something?

How can I make `xrandr -o normal` run every time the laptop wakes from suspend? Maybe a hackish solution, but it might work, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if what you describe is a bug, but you can run `xrandr -o normal` at wake-up from suspend by doing the following (based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1041358/618353) and the [comment below it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92218/how-to-execute-a-command-after-resume-from-suspend#comment1953734_1041358)):

1. Create a shell script named `xrandr_normal.sh` (you can use another name if you wish) that runs your `xrandr` command:

   ```
   nano /path/to/script/xrandr_normal.sh
   ```

   Put the following inside:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash
   DISPLAY=:0.0 ; export DISPLAY
   xrandr -o normal
   ```
2. Give execution rights to your script:

   ```
   chmod u+x /path/to/script/xrandr_normal.sh
   ```
3. Create a service file that will run your script after suspend (you can use whatever name you wish for the service file):

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/xrandr_normal.service
   ```

   Put the following inside:

   ```bsh
   [Unit]
   Description=Some description
   Before=sleep.target
   StopWhenUnneeded=yes

   [Service]
   User=YOUR_USERNAME
   Type=oneshot
   RemainAfterExit=yes
   ExecStop=/path/to/script/xrandr_normal.sh

   [Install]
   WantedBy=sleep.target
   ```

   Make sure to replace `YOUR_USERNAME` in the first line below `[Service]` with your actual username and put the correct path to your script in `ExecStop`.
4. Enable the service you created:

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable xrandr_normal
   ```
5. Start the service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start xrandr_normal
   ```
6. As the author of the answer that this one is based on suggests, you can check for errors if the service does not work after suspend with the following command:

   ```
   journalctl -u xrandr_normal.service
   ```

Comment: What a pain, but I guess this works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Manually switching the orientation of the screen to portrait (left or right) and then back to landscape in display settings seems to have fixed the issue.