# How to rotate screen in Ubuntu using terminal?

Tags: 18.04, screen, gnome-shell, display-rotation

Recently I booted *Ubuntu 18.04 Live USB* and I faced annoying problem. Screen was rotated and there was **no rotate options** in `settings`. I had to search not so obvious places in Internet, so I share this Q&A.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You should use *`xrandr`* command.
**`xrandr -o normal`** takes your screen back to **normal (landscape) rotation**.

### Ubuntu 22:

instead of `xrandr -o normal` you should use `xrandr -orientation normal`

Comment: How to persist this across restarts?

Comment: @danjah Unfortunately I didn't try to persist it. It's probably not the best solution, but you can try to add new line with `xrandr -o normal` to you `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any more on Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: a partly solution to rotate via keyboard shortcut is found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465395/20661

Comment: Great answer. How do you do this with a dual monitor setup, where one should be flipped to normal mode and the other should be flipped left?

Comment: @ComputerScientist I'm sorry, I've never used Ubuntu with dual monitor :(

Comment: this appears to be a solution if you're running the x11 display system.  What if it's just the server without that running?  meaning only the terminal is being ran.

Comment: Found the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/452772/1805

Answer (score 9):

You can use these commands:

```
xrandr --output $(xrandr |grep eDP|cut -d" " -f1) --rotate left
xrandr --output $(xrandr |grep eDP|cut -d" " -f1) --rotate normal
```

also `right` and `inverted`

I created a script here: https://gist.github.com/rubo77/d43cc5b3ff65d6df28b8b8c3c089f23b

with that script, you can simply call

```
rotatescreen.sh -r
rotatescreen.sh -l
rotatescreen.sh -i
rotatescreen.sh -n
```

---

Alternative, you can use CTRL+F8 to rotate using

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.keybindings rotate-monitor "['XF86RotateWindows', '<Control>F8']"
```

see https://askubuntu.com/a/1184316/34298

Comment: Only CTRL+F8 solved it for me. Thanks