# Ubuntu 20.04 - screen keeps rotating on its own

Tags: 20.04, display-rotation

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell Latitude laptop.

After a few minutes, the screen suddenly rotated 90 degrees to the right.
It just seemed to have happened on its own. Possibly shortly after installing Ubuntu base/firmware updates that were suggested by the system (from the official repository).

[How to rotate screen in Ubuntu using terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043644/how-to-rotate-screen-in-ubuntu-using-terminal) taught me how to rotate it back. The problem is that it doesn't stick.

The screen still rotates occasionally, seemingly on its own.
Even when it's ok, when I log off - the user selection screen is rotated.

I found a "Lock Screen Rotation" option in the top-right system menu, but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

It happened shortly after I installed Ubuntu, on a fairly clean system, with no special customizations or tweaks.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn off screen rotation in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035209/how-to-turn-off-screen-rotation-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts). The `Super + O` (o) key combo seems like the safest option. `Super` should be the Windows key.

Comment: Thanks @l3l_aze. I actually tried this before (that's what I referred to as "Lock Screen Rotation" in my question). The screen still rotated after that. However, strangely enough, it stopped happening. Maybe one of the things I tried required a full reboot? I just hope it doesn't come back...