# How to fix login screen (lightdm) orientation and prompt with my two monitors?

Tags: login, multiple-monitors, display, lightdm, display-resolution

I have Ubuntu MATE 16.04.6 LTS installed on a system with two monitors.
They act normally when I login to default MATE 1.12.1 session.

But the LightDM login screen looks weird on both screens:

1. 1600x900 normal landscape (no rotation)

   > [image: 1600x900 landscape]
2. 1280x1024 left portrait rotation

   > [image: 1280x1024]

Details about lightdm:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i lightdm
ii  liblightdm-gobject-1-0:amd64   1.18.3-0ubuntu1.1  amd64  LightDM GObject client library
ii  lightdm                        1.18.3-0ubuntu1.1  amd64  Display Manager
ii  lightdm-gtk-greeter            2.0.1-2ubuntu4     amd64  simple display manager (GTK+ greeter)
ii  lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings   1.2.1-0ubuntu1     all    settings editor for the LightDM GTK+ Greeter
ii  ubuntu-mate-lightdm-theme      16.04.7            all    LightDM theme and default configuration for Ubuntu MATE

$ cat .dmrc 
[Desktop]
Session=mate
```

Details from `/etc/default/grub.cfg`:

```
$ cat /etc/default/grub | grep LINUX_DEFAULT
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="verbose INIT_VERBOSE=y noplymouth"
```

I see this on every boot-up and currently I enter my password blindly.

How and where should I fix this problem?

**Update 1:** passing `nomodeset` in GRUB fixes LightDM login, but disables screen rotation of right monitor.

**Update 2:** temporary fixed by installing `kylin-greeter` ("The greeter for the Kylin desktop fork from unity-greeter."), but still need solution for original problem with LightDM and `unity-greeter`.

Answer (score 1):

For screen rotation restoration; Try this...

**For the initial text console?**

Check:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/237963/how-do-i-rotate-my-display-when-not-using-an-x-server

... and/or check the content of /etc/default/grub
and make sure it contains something similar to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noplymouth video=efifb fbcon=rotate:3"
```

then do

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

This should make all *after* the grub menus/screens be rotated accordingly.

**For X?**
Arrange your screens with the "System Settings" > "Displays"
Then make sure that `/var/lib/lightdm/.config/monitors.xml` is `lightdm`-owned copy of `$HOME/.config/monitors.xml`. Take into use: reboot to see the effect.

Comment: Both solutions does not work. GRUB one rotates both screens, LightDM config is not applied even if I copy it manually with `sudo cp $HOME/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/lightdm/.config/monitors.xml; sudo chown -R lightdm: /var/lib/lightdm`.

Comment: You should have instances saying other than "normal" in the output from grep on both files, as in: `sudo grep rotation /var/lib/lightdm/.config/monitors.xml  .config/monitors.xml` - if you do have it, then I have no more clues.

Comment: BTW, do: `sudo chown -R lightdm:lightdm /var/lib/lightdm` to ensure the group is set too !